# How can I draw 16 pin macro by use circuit-tikz package?

Tags: graphics, circuitikz

[image: macro 16 pin]

I want to draw this macro by use circuit-tikz package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @Holene.Thank you for your guidance.You are right...

Comment: Though Gonzalo the madman did just that! :-) Such procrastination!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an `and gate` from the `circuits.logic.IEC` library from TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz,siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[circuit logic IEC] 
\draw (4,0) node[european and port] (euand) {};
\node[
  and gate,
  inputs={nnnnnnnn},
  and gate IEC symbol={},
  text height=3cm,
  text width=2cm,
] (A) {};
\foreach \Valor in {1,...,8}
{
  \draw ([xshift=-20pt]A.input \Valor) -- (A.input \Valor) node[right] {$I_{\number\numexpr\Valor-1\relax}$};
}
\foreach \Valor [count=\xi] in {12,0,-12}
{
  \draw ([xshift=\Valor]A.south) node[above] {$S_{\number\numexpr\xi-1\relax}$}  -- ++(0,-10pt);  
}
\node[left] at (A.output) {$Z$};
\draw (A.output) -| (euand.in 1);
\draw (A.output) -| (euand.in 2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]